# Any comments on career with FBI Cybercrime & Forensics?

Tags: untagged

I'm interested in if anyone here as a better inside perspective on what working for the FBI as a Special Agent in their Cyber program is like. The majority of online articles are focused towards the criminal and terrorism investigations. I found one interesting article about a large bust of illegal online hackers and identify theft ring, but besides that the web has been remarkably scarce of interesting information.

Thought I'd ask if anyone had some inside or knowledgable perspective on their work. I already know it's insanely difficult to get into the FBI career wise, but I'd still like to know.

Comment: This should be a Community Wiki post

Comment: ?? IT WAS flagged as a community wiki?

Answer (score 2):

How do you feel about searching for child porn?  All the time?  I took a digital forensics class in college, and a few FBI agents came to talk to the class about what they did.  2-3 weeks a month, that was it.

It didn't sound very fun at all.

Comment: do they have any choice, as i've heard that it was a particular area, but also with fraud, etc. I wonder if you can choose.

Comment: +1 | I worked with a woman who did computer forensics privately, and she said the same thing about searching for child porn all the time. It was one of the reasons why she got away from that career, actually.

Comment: that's why I wasn't wanting to go federal... to avoid that as the primary focus...

Comment: Lee: What's the "F" in FBI stand for again? :)

I think that you get what jobs they send you.  Some days you're searching for terrorists, some days you're looking for naked pictures of 12 year olds.

Answer (score 0):

I have no actual evidence of this really, but I would guess the NSA might be where more of the 'exciting stuff' is happening judging by [this NSA patent list](http://cryptome.org/nsa-patents.htm).

Comment: hmm. I'll have to look into that as well. I don't relish the thought of doing nothing by p0rn tracking.... that's why I moved away from wanting local cyber police, as I thought the FBI would have more variety and chances to get away from that.